# Get Twitter trends when specifying a WOEID

Tags: twitter

Hi all i would like to get a list of trending topic from a specific country.

You can look at the [documentation here](http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/44418.json).

The format of the feed is

api.twitter.com/1/trends/woeid.format

When searching for trends in London(WEOIP=44418) it works perfectly.

api.twitter.com/1/trends/44418.json

But for some reason it does not work for South Africa(WEOIP=23424942)

api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424942.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trending data is available for certain countries, but it is not available for South Africa.

There is a list of available locations (which may be out of date, posted on February 4, 2010) at the bottom of this blog post:
https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2010/woeids-in-twitters-trends.html

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API provides a method to get available locations for trending topics. You should first fetch those available locations and then make a request to load trending topics for one of those locations by specifying its WOEID. See [Twitter API reference for available locations](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554752/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-trends-available).

Comment: If you're in a hurry, you can fetch it in this address https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/available.json